# Yii2: The Depdrop widget form Kartik keeps loading

Tags: php, yii2, widget, dropdown

I am using the Depdrop Widget from Kartik, but a field keeps loading when it tries to find the data to populate the dropdown.

[image: Field not loading...]

I recently updated my widgets via Composer and got this error **(i am not sure if this is the cause)**.

The field in the view:

```
        <?= $form->field($model, 'IdCamion')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
            'type' => DepDrop::TYPE_SELECT2,
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'depends' => ['produccion-idcliente', 'produccion-tipotarifa'],
                'placeholder' => 'Seleccione...',
                'url' => Url::to(['/operaciones/camiones'])
            ]
        ]); ?>
```

and the action to populate the dropdown:

```
public function actionCamiones()
{
    $out = [];
    if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {

        $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
        $data_lista = array();
        if ($parents != null) {
            $cliente = $parents[0];
            $tarifa = $parents[1];
            $array = Tarifa::find()->where(['IdCliente' => $cliente])->andWhere(['TipoTarifa' => $tarifa])
                ->andWhere(['eliminado' => 0])->andWhere(['estado' => 5])->groupby('TamanoCamion')->all();
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                $camiones = Camiones::find()->where(['Tamano' => $value->TamanoCamion])->andwhere('Estatus = 1 or Estatus = 18')->all();
                foreach ($camiones as $key => $camion) {
                    $data_lista[] = array('id' => $camion->NumeroCamion, 'name' => $camion->NumeroCamion);
                }
            }
            $out = $data_lista;
            echo Json::encode(['output' => $out, 'selected' => '']);
            return;
        }
    }
    echo Json::encode(['output' => '', 'selected' => '']);
}
```

i am getting the data like this (the output I'm putting is **longer** but i cut it short to not make it tedious):

```
{"output":[{"id":"124","name":"124"},{"id":"161","name":"161"},        
{"id":"163","name":"163"},{"id":"125","name":"125"}, 
{"id":"112","name":"112"},{"id":"113","name":"113"}, 
{"id":"114","name":"114"},{"id":"115","name":"115"}, 
{"id":"492","name":"492"},{"id":"493","name":"493"}],"selected":""}
An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException: Headers already sent in 
/var/www/html/sat2-panama/controllers/OperacionesController.php on line 
1618. in /var/www/html/sat2- 
panama/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:366
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/sat2-panama/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(339): 
yii\web\Response->sendHeaders()
#1 /var/www/html/sat2- 
panama/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(135): yii\web\Response- 
>send()
#2 /var/www/html/sat2- 
panama/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(111): 
yii\web\ErrorHandler- 
>renderException(Object(yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException))
#3 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler- 
>handleException(Object(yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException))
#4 {main}
Previous exception:
yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException: Headers already sent in 
/var/www/html/sat2-panama/controllers/OperacionesController.php on line 
1618. in /var/www/html/sat2- 
panama/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:366
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/sat2-panama/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(339): 
yii\web\Response->sendHeaders()
#1 /var/www/html/sat2- 
panama/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): yii\web\Response- 
>send()
#2 /var/www/html/sat2-panama/web/index.php(12): yii\base\Application- 
>run()
#3 {main}
```

It is expected to have the data in this way:

```
{output: [{id: "124", name: "124"}, {id: "161", name: "161"}, {id: "163", 
name: "163"},…],…}
output: [{id: "124", name: "124"}, {id: "161", name: "161"}, {id: "163", 
name: "163"},…]
selected: ""
```

The weird part comes when you select another option from the parents dropdowns, it populates the dropdown correctly with the data.

[image: Field populated.]

The problem is with the option "Viaje" in the field "Tarifa", i don't know if this is a problem with data handling or data size, but with the other options, the data is smaller and populate the dropdown correctly.

**EDIT:** i did another test:

i used another function to populate the dropdown with the problem:

```
public function PruebaDataDrop()
 {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 194; $i++) {
        $data_lista[] = array('id' => $i, 'name' => $i);
    }
    return $data_lista;
}
```

it works only with 195 positions in the Array (0-194), when i tried 195 or more, it gives me the same problem (the dropdown keeps loading).

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: First of all, did you closed this action for `GET` requests?, Next if `$_POST` will be empty you `echo` response, but you supposed to return Json in both scenarios. Second, Are you sure that `POST` request that you do, does not throw any errors? Maybe at some point with selected fields it does not have model. Could you post what dates DepDrop  trying to post, and what are you get in controller on both foreeach loops?

Comment: Hello Serghei, i really don't understand what you mean with the first point, and the second, yes, the $_POST doesn't have any errors:

not working test:

Array
    (
    [depdrop_parents] => Array
        (
            [0] => 53
            [1] => 1
        )

    [depdrop_all_params] => Array
        (
            [produccion-idcliente] => 53
            [produccion-tipotarifa] => 1
        )
    )

this is what i am getting in the $_POST.

Comment: Then, when it does the query to get the data:

Test Working: array [0]-[71]
Test not working: array [0]-[162]

i've tried returning Json in both scenarios too, same problem.

Comment: I do not understand your `EDIT`, explain. Also about 'points': You need to add in behaviors to `verbs` a section `'camiones' => '['POST'],'` to close access to controller action from GET, and post you DB data when error occur.

Comment: i've explained my "EDIT" better.

Comment: i've already added the new section in `verbs`, it seems to not affect anything.

Comment: What Yii Debug and Console shows you? is there any errors?, Also take a look in `runtime/logs/` last one file.

Comment: it shows what i did put in the question, "An Error occurred while handling another error:".

Comment: Have you checked your logs?

Comment: runtime/logs:

`2019-07-08 10:39:13 [::1][19][-][error][yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException] yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException: Headers already sent in C:\xampp\htdocs\sat2-panama\controllers\OperacionesController.php on line 1618. in`

Comment: post line 1618 pls

Comment: line 1618:  `echo Json::encode(['output' => $out, 'selected' => '']);`

Comment: edit both lines where you return JSON to: `return Json::encode(['output' => $out, 'selected' => '']);` and `return Json::encode(['output' => '', 'selected' => '']);`, that's what i told you in first comment, You should not echo anything in controller.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much Serghei it worked. Put the Answer and i will mark it is correct!

it's weird why i had that "echo" in the controller, maybe bad usage of copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
return Json::encode(['output' => $out, 'selected' => '']);
```

and

```
return Json::encode(['output' => '', 'selected' => '']);
```

That will solve your issue.